# vb6 program from java using jacob?

Tags: java, vb6, jacob

I use [jacob](http://www.jacob.ca/) and [Sample Program](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/114094-using-dll-library-in-java-application-using-jacob/). I have bean finished DLL(`ANT_Registration.dll`) registeration to `.Net Framwork`.
I cannot call fucntion `Decryption` from `vb6` program.

```
public class Encoder {
    public String encode(String value) {
        ActiveXComponent comp = new ActiveXComponent("ANT_Registration.Registration");
        return Dispatch.call(comp, "Decryption", value).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
        String value = encoder.encode("admin");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Error Stack Eclipse console

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7798e3be, pid=4744, tid=3124
#
# JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\dev\eclipse\hwak-framework\read-dll\hs_err_pid4744.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

[error occurred during error reporting , id 0xc0000005]
```

hs_err_pid4744.log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7798e3be, pid=4744, tid=3124
#
# JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x023b9400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3124, stack(0x00280000,0x002d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x04b462ec

Registers:
EAX=0x40024e6a, EBX=0x0033b7d8, ECX=0x04aa0000, EDX=0x0033b7d8
ESP=0x002cf654, EBP=0x002cf688, ESI=0x04b462e8, EDI=0x0033b7d0
EIP=0x7798e3be, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x002cf654)
0x002cf654:   00000000 04aa0000 0033b7d8 00000513
0x002cf664:   00000000 0100b7d8 00000000 00002498
0x002cf674:   01013750 002cf5b0 70a87826 002cfdd4
0x002cf684:   0033b7d0 002cf6a0 7798e023 0033b7d8
0x002cf694:   04ab0120 0033b7d8 0033b7d0 002cf6b4
0x002cf6a4:   76d414ad 04aa0000 00000000 0033b7d8
0x002cf6b4:   02441f18 1000a641 04aa0000 00000000
0x002cf6c4:   0033b7d8 000000a9 10009e9b 0033b7d8 

Instructions: (pc=0x7798e3be)
0x7798e39e:   7a f8 80 7f 07 05 0f 84 eb 4b 06 00 8b 07 8b f7
0x7798e3ae:   c1 ee 03 33 f0 33 35 a4 00 a6 77 89 7d fc 33 f1
0x7798e3be:   8b 46 04 89 45 f4 c6 47 07 80 c6 47 06 00 8b 5e
0x7798e3ce:   08 8b 4e 0c 89 5d e0 83 c3 01 89 4d e4 83 d1 01 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x40024e6a is an unknown value
EBX=0x0033b7d8 is an unknown value
ECX=0x04aa0000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0033b7d8 is an unknown value
ESP=0x002cf654 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x023b9400
EBP=0x002cf688 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x023b9400
ESI=0x04b462e8 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0033b7d0 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00280000,0x002d0000],  sp=0x002cf654,  free space=317k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]  RtlInitUnicodeString+0x196
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e023]  RtlFreeHeap+0x7e
C  [kernel32.dll+0x114ad]  HeapFree+0x14

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;III[Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;[I)Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;+0
j  com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;I[Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;[I)Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;+27
j  com.jacob.com.Dispatch.callN(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;+11
j  com.jacob.com.Dispatch.call(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/jacob/com/Variant;+10
j  com.mutu.dll.Encoder.encode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+14
j  com.mutu.dll.Encoder.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0245e400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1564, stack(0x04920000,0x04970000)]
  0x02448400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5032, stack(0x04890000,0x048e0000)]
  0x02445400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3812, stack(0x04800000,0x04850000)]
  0x02442400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4424, stack(0x04770000,0x047c0000)]
  0x0243bc00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=196, stack(0x046e0000,0x04730000)]
  0x0243a000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4268, stack(0x04650000,0x046a0000)]
=>0x023b9400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3124, stack(0x00280000,0x002d0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x023fdc00 VMThread [stack: 0x045c0000,0x04610000] [id=6036]
  0x02470000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x049b0000,0x04a00000] [id=2968]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 385K [0x24600000, 0x24b50000, 0x29b50000)
  eden space 4416K,   8% used [0x24600000, 0x246605e8, 0x24a50000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24a50000, 0x24a50000, 0x24ad0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24ad0000, 0x24ad0000, 0x24b50000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29b50000, 0x2a600000, 0x34600000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29b50000, 0x29b50000, 0x29b50200, 0x2a600000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 98K [0x34600000, 0x35200000, 0x38600000)
   the space 12288K,   0% used [0x34600000, 0x34618bf0, 0x34618c00, 0x35200000)
    ro space 10240K,  54% used [0x38600000, 0x38b7e770, 0x38b7e800, 0x39000000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x39000000, 0x396a4ac8, 0x396a4c00, 0x39c00000)

Code Cache  [0x024c0000, 0x02530000, 0x044c0000)
 total_blobs=133 nmethods=9 adapters=61 free_code_cache=33098624 largest_free_block=0

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x77960000 - 0x77ae0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76d30000 - 0x76e40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x764b0000 - 0x764f7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x772a0000 - 0x77340000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x76fbc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76d10000 - 0x76d29000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76b90000 - 0x76c80000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75360000 - 0x753c0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75350000 - 0x7535c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x755a0000 - 0x756a0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x757a0000 - 0x75830000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76aa0000 - 0x76aaa000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x77010000 - 0x770ad000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x753e0000 - 0x75440000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76ac0000 - 0x76b8c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db4f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x75130000 - 0x75162000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x70860000 - 0x708ac000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x75580000 - 0x75585000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10018000     C:\Windows\System32\jacob.dll
0x76c80000 - 0x76d0f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x76780000 - 0x768dc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x77340000 - 0x773c3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x732e0000 - 0x732f6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x732a0000 - 0x732db000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x73290000 - 0x7329e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x74c30000 - 0x74cb0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x11000000 - 0x1100b000     C:\Windows\SysWow64\ANT_Registration.dll
0x740c0000 - 0x7420d000     C:\Windows\SysWow64\MSVBVM50.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.mutu.dll.Encoder
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
PATH=D:/java/eclipse/jre/bin/client;D:/java/eclipse/jre/bin;D:/java/eclipse/jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.28\bin;D:\My Home;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn;;D:\java\eclipse;
USERNAME=CycDemo
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 5974108k(2913604k free), swap 11946352k(7605492k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.0-b11) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_25-b06), built on Apr 14 2011 01:04:32 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Tue Aug 12 12:22:03 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Hey CycDemo, were you able to solve this?

Comment: @hectorg87, not yet fri